# Checking if values from different lists are less than x

Tags: python

I can't use csv module so I'm opening a csv file like this:

```
def readdata(filename):
    res = []
    tmp = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        l = f.readlines()
        for i in range(len(l)):
            tmp.append(l[i].strip().split(';'))

    for i in range(len(tmp)):
        for j in range(len(tmp[i])):
            if j > len(res)-1:
                res.append([])
            res[j].append(tmp[i][j])
    return res


res_count_file = "count.csv"

data_count_file = readdata(res_count_file)
```

This csv file contain this:

```
ro1;ro2;ro3
5;3;5
8;2;4
6;2;666
15;6;3
2;1;
6;9;7
```

Now my function read this and splits them into a list of 3 lists :

```
[['ro1', '5', '8', '6', '15', '2', '6'], ['ro2', '3', '2', '2', '6', '1', '9'], ['ro3', '5', '4', '666', '3', '', '7']]
```

I need to check if the values of a row are each less then x(let's say x = 10), and if they're not then :score+= 1
For exemple:

```
5;3;5  //none of them are greater then x so score += 1
8;2;4  //none of them are greater then x so score += 1
15;6;3 // 15 is greater then x so nothing happens
2;1;   // none of them are greater then x so score += 1 even if there is nothing in ro3, I need to convert the empty string "''" into 0
```

Now I've tried to call this function in a for loop to check if a number is less then X and to increment score if this returns true but I can't figure out how to check all 3 of the numbers in R01 R02 R03 as shown in the exemple.

```
def apprenant_fiable(data,index_of,i):


    if data[index_of][i] == "":

        return True

    elif int(data[index_of][i]) <= 10 :
            #print(data[index_of][i],"***PASS")
        return True
    else :
            #print(data[index_of][i],"***FAIL")
        return False
```

The goal is to output the total score.

Comment: What is the final output? Total score?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I need the final score out of all this

Comment: can't use pandas? it would take 2 lines of code...

Comment: curious as to why you can't use the csv module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` on a generator:

```
lst = [['ro1', '5', '8', '6', '15', '2', '6'], ['ro2', '3', '2', '2', '6', '1', '9'], ['ro3', '5', '4', '666', '3', '0', '7']]

val = 10
score = sum(all(y <= val for y in x) for x in zip(*[map(int, x[1:]) for x in lst]))

# 4
```

Note that I've replaced empty string in the list to `'0'`, which you need to handle while forming the list.

---

```
val = 10
for x in zip(*[map(int, x[1:]) for x in lst]):
    if all(y <= val for y in x):
        print(x)
```

This will now print out all rows that contributed to adding `score`.

Comment: This works perfectly but I can't figure out how exactly I could apply it to my program. I need to find out witch row of values generated the score+1 in order to apply it to smth else. Could you give me a moment of your time in PM? Or there is not a pm possible here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @FelixDumitrascu, No PMs. See the answer you want above (edited just now). :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? where list_of_3_lists is your result of reading the input file

```
total = 0
for l in list_of_3_lists:
    if all([int(t) > 10 for t in l[1:]]):
        total +=1
print(total)
```

Comment: if all([t > 10 for t in l[1:]):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @FelixDumitrascu: `if all([t > 10 for t in l[1:]]):`; btw you need to change to integer before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the head of your function:

```
def apprenant_fiable(data, index_of, i):
                           ########
```

You specifically tell your function to look at only one of the three lists.  Get rid of this.  Inside the function you will somewhere have

```
    for value, index in enumerate(data)
```

You will need to check all the values before deciding what to return.
If you can't figure out how to do this, there are many places to teach you how to look for presence of a certain quality in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easly using the `pandas` module

```
import pandas as pd

# read the csv
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delimiter=';').fillna(0)
# leave only the rows with sum greater then 10
print(df[df.sum(axis=1) > 10].shape[0])
```